# Cleaning up excel document - formatting cells based on its content

Tags: python, pandas

Quite new in Python, and doing my first project - excel data cleaning.
The idea is to check data before uploading it to the system. Cells which do not meet requirements have to be highlighted and comment should be added into the `comment` column.

Requirements to check:

1. Mark First or Last Names which contain numbers/symbols - action: highlight the cell and add a comment to the comment column
2. Check empty cells - action: highlight the cell and add a comment

I tried different ways (especially using IF statement) on how to highlight cells which do no meet requirements and comment at the same time, but nothing works

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_i = pd.DataFrame({'Email' : ['john@yahoo.com','john@outlook.com','john@gmail.com'], 'First Name': ['JOHN','   roman2   ',''], 'Last Name': ['Smith','','132'], 'Comments':['','','']})
emails_to_exclude = ('@gmail', '@yahoo')

print(df_i)

#Proper names
def proper_name(name):
    return name.str.title()

df_i['First Name'] = proper_name(df_i['First Name'] )
df_i['Last Name'] = proper_name(df_i['Last Name'] )

#Trim spaces
def trim(cell):
        return cell.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

df_i = trim(df_i)

#Check public email domains
df_i.loc[df_i['Email'].str.contains('|'.join(emails_to_exclude), case=False),'Comments'] = df_i['Comments'].astype(str) + 'public email domain'

#Check first and last name

list_excl = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
df_i.loc[df_i['First Name'].str.contains('|'.join(list_excl), case=False), 'Comments']  = df_i['Comments'].astype(str) + " Check 'First Name'"
df_i.loc[df_i['Last Name'].str.contains('|'.join(list_excl), case=False), 'Comments']  = df_i['Comments'].astype(str) + " Check 'Last Name'"

print(df_i)
```

Comment: hi, what do you mean by *highlighting* a cell?

Comment: Hi, I mean changing cell color (background color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function that uses `re` to see if a string matches a defined pattern. I understood that the desired pattern is a sequence of upper- or lower-case letters (not sure if the names can contain whitespace characters).

For the formatting part, use `df.style`. Basically you write a function that defines how each cell should be formatted using CSS. You will need to export to excel (csv does not contain any information about the formatting). You can also render it as an html table. [Read more](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). Note that after using `df.style`, the object that you are using is no longer `pd.DataFrame`. Rather, it is `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler`. You should do whatever you want to do with your DataFrame **before** styling it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

def highlight_invalid(string, invalid_colour='yellow', empty_colour='red'):
    if string:
        # The string contains only one or more letters
        pattern = re.compile(r'^([A-z])+$')
        if pattern.match(string):
            # do not highlight valid strings
            return ''
        else:
            # highlight non-matching strings in invalid_colour
            return f'background-color: {invalid_colour}'
    else:
        # highlight empty strings in empty_colour
         return f'background-color: {empty_colour}'

cols = ['First Name', 'Last Name']
for col in cols:
    # It didn't work when I tried it with missing values, so make sure to replace
    df_i[col] = df_i[col].replace(np.nan, '')

# Apply the highlighting function to every cell of 'First Name' and 'Last Name'
df_i = df_i.style.applymap(highlight_invalid, subset=cols)

df_i.to_excel(fname)
```

Maybe you want to write a separate function that does the data verification and use it both in highlighting and adding a comment. I will leave that to you as that is not related to formatting per se and should be asked as a separate question.